# Bad training results when I am trying to find out defected and non-defected solar cells

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to classify which are defected solar cells. I have a huge dataset of both defected plates and non-defected solar cells. As per a few suggestions from research papers I have been using the VGG 16 model for the training purpose. But even after 3 epochs, it is showing 100 % accuracy. I don't why it is coming like this. Is there any other way to solve this problem, any other Algorithm.
I am uploading some of the defected cells which I have in my dataset

[image: This is the kind of defect image I have[[![]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNHYa.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNHYa.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYLf1.jpg)

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# re-size all the images to this
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]

train_path = 'Datasets/Train'
valid_path = 'Datasets/Test'

# add preprocessing layer to the front of VGG
vgg = VGG16(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# don't train existing weights
for layer in vgg.layers:
  layer.trainable = False



  # useful for getting number of classes
folders = glob('Datasets/Train/*')


# our layers - you can add more if you want
x = Flatten()(vgg.output)
# x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs=prediction)

# view the structure of the model
model.summary()

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Datasets/Train',
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Datasets/Test',
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

# fit the model
r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=10,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)
# loss
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='train loss')
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='val loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('LossVal_loss')

# accuracies
plt.plot(r.history['acc'], label='train acc')
plt.plot(r.history['val_acc'], label='val acc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('AccVal_acc')

import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import load_model

model.save('defect_features_new_model.h5')
```

Comment: is the 100% accuracy in train or validation?

Comment: This is what I am getting ,,      Epoch 10/10
43/43 [==============================] - 21s 481ms/step - loss: 0.0118 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0177 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Comment: So what is the problem? Your accuracy on validation is also 100%. Is it good?

Comment: I suspect something odd, getting 100% even after 3 epochs. Or else is there any other good method or any deep learning method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the images are too simple and do not contain any complicated data. Hence they tend to overfit the VGG16 model. VGG16 models are generally trained on much more complicated data. You can try defining your own convolutional neural network. Since you are already using keras you can create sequential model to define your own model with minimum as 2 or 3 convolutional layers[Please refer the link for keras sequential model](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Your data for the network looks very simple so it is not unexpected that you achieve high accuracy. Remember the network trains in batches so for every 32 images it goes through a back propagation cycle and updates the weights accordingly. So if you have a lot of images which you say you do then you are executing a lot of iterations on the weights.
I do not see a problem here. You are not  over training in the sense that your validation accuracy is 100%. Certainly you could get good results with a simpler model but why bother your results are what you would want.